# How to '$parse' a scope object in a directive passing the entire object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing

If I have this **controller**:

```
myApp.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {    
 $scope.obj = {
  name: "John",
  lastname: "Preston"
 }
});
```

with this **html**

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div my-attr="obj" my-directive>Click here</div>
    <pre>{{obj | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

I want to change the value of `lastname` in a **directive** with **$parse**. I know that if I pass the object property like this:

```
<div my-attr="obj.lastname" my-directive>Click here</div>
```

This directive do the work:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function( $parse, $log ) {
    return function( scope, el, attrs ) {

        var model = $parse( attrs.myAttr );

        $log.log( model(scope) );

        el.bind('click', function() {
            model.assign(scope, "Watts");
            scope.$apply();
            $log.log( model(scope) ); // Now here obj.lastname is Watts
        })
    }
});
```

But how could be the code inside the directive without passing the property? I mean, like this: `my-attr="obj"`

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the property?  You just want Angular to bind the value to the controller without using a directive?  Some other reason?

Comment: Really not clear what you want to do just passing "obj" in. Explain use case in a little more detail

Comment: My only reason is that I just want to know if this is possible (:

Comment: of course it's possible if you want to hard code the property name in directive. Also wouldn't need to use `$parse` if you used isolated scope and let angular set up the 2 way binding for you

Comment: Ok, if I pass the entire `obj`, how can I `model.assign(scope, "Watts");` to only the `lastname` property? Because if I do it with this code, replace the entire scope.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I know I can do it with an isolated scope, but I just want to know if it is possible with `$parse`. And if is possible, I want an example of code.

Comment: could use `scope.$eval(attrs.myAttr)` instead. Since it's an object just update the object properties

Comment: Yes, with `scope.$eval(attrs.myAttr)` work. But my question is still: It is possible to do it with `$parse`?. I don't know what anymore to say (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found 2 ways to get this:

**1) $parse** (my favorite)

I just got it using: `$parse( 'obj.lastname' );` on this way:

*The html:*

```
<div my-directive>Click here</div>
```

*The directive:*

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function( $parse, $log ) {
    return function( scope, el, attrs ) {

        var model = $parse( 'obj.lastname' );

        $log.log( model(scope) );

        el.bind('click', function() {
            model.assign(scope, "Watts");
            scope.$apply();
            $log.log( model(scope) ); // Now here obj.lastname is Watts
        })
    }
});
```

**2) $eval** (interesting)

*The html:*

```
<div my-attr="obj" my-directive>Click here</div>
```

*The directive:*

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function( $parse, $log ) {
    return function( scope, el, attrs ) {

        var model = scope.$eval(attrs.myAttr);

        $log.log( model );

        el.bind('click', function() {
            model.lastname = 'Watts';
            scope.$apply();
            $log.log( model ); // Now here obj.lastname is Watts
        })
    }
});
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass in the entire object. but then in the directive you have to populate all the properties of the object. For example:

html:

```
<div my-attr="obj" my-directive>Click here</div>
```

in your directive:

```
el.bind('click', function() {
        model.assign(scope, {lastname:'Watt', gender: 'Male'});
        scope.$apply();
        $log.log( model(scope) ); // Now here obj.lastname is Watt
    })
```

I probably won't do that, but that's how I would do it

Comment: Yes, it is a possibility. Look for my answer.

Comment: I like your 1st answer better :)